# Using an arduino as intermediary between a client and server computer

Tags: python, sockets, arduino

I'm working on a system that uses 2 computers and an arduino connected to a sonar; the function of each is as follows:

The first computer is the 'Command Computer', and sends out commands to the arduinos to take sensor measurements.

The ethernet arduino accepts commands from the Command Computer, and then sends the results of the measurements to the Action Computer.

The Action Computer performs an action based off of the result of the measurement.

All communication is done with the python socket module and the arduino Ethernet library.

For testing purposes, I'm simulating the Command and Action computer on the same computer but with different sockets.  The Command Computer is simulated by client.py, and the Action Computer is simulated by server.py.  If I point them directly at each other (skipping the arduino), everything works as expected.

However, when I add the arduino in the middle, I run into issues of the arduino not responding to all of my commands sent to it, and the whole system slows down.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to start troubleshooting this -- I can't tell if the arduino can't handle so many requests in quick succession, or if perhaps I'm handling the messages in a clunky way that results in the socket being unavailable too frequently.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated -- code is below.

client.py

```
import socket
import time

while True:
    try:
        client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client_socket.connect(("192.168.0.250", 10220))
        #client_socket.connect(("192.168.0.100", 8220))
        data = "GET\nSONAR\n\n"
        print 'send to server: ' + data
        client_socket.send(data)
        #receive = client_socket.recv(2048)
        #print receive
        client_socket.close()
        time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as msg:
        print msg
```

This talks to simpleSonarTest.ino:

```
#include <avr/wdt.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <MyClient.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//localClient parameters, for sending data to the server.
byte mac[] = {0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0F, 0x03, 0x58};
byte ip[] = {192,168,0,250};
byte server[] = {192, 168, 0, 100};
int serverPort = 8220;
MyClient* localClient;

//Server parameters, for acting like a server.
int localPort = serverPort + 1000;
int pollPort = serverPort + 2000;
EthernetServer localServer = EthernetServer(localPort);
EthernetServer pollServer = EthernetServer(pollPort);

//sonar stuff
String content_string;
int NUM_SONARS = 1;
int sonarPin[] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
int triggerPin = 6;
int sonarThreshold = 12.0;
int sonarState[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
long pulse;
int numPulses = 3;
int pulseArray[] = {0,0,0,0,0};
int filteredMode = 0;
float time;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  wdt_enable(WDTO_8S);

  localClient = new MyClient(mac, ip);
  localClient->connect(server, serverPort);

  pollServer.begin();

  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_SONARS; i++) {
    pinMode(sonarPin[i], INPUT);
  }
  pinMode(triggerPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW);
  time = 0;
}

void loop() {
  wdt_reset();
  time = millis();

  EthernetClient pollClient = pollServer.available();
  if (pollClient) {
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    String receivingString = "";
    while (pollClient.connected()) {
      //while the socket is open
      if(pollClient.available()) {
        //and there is something to read on the port, then read the available characters
        char c = pollClient.read();
        receivingString += c;
        //share with the serial monitor:
        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
          pollClient.println("Received message.");
          break;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        } 
        else if (c != '\r') {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);

    // parse the incoming data
    String command = split(receivingString,'\n',0);
    String payload = split(receivingString,'\n',1);

    String key = split(payload,'=',0);
    String value = split(payload,'=',1);

    //PARSE THE KEY AND VALUE NOW
    if(command == "GET") {
      if(key == "SONAR") {
        pingSonars();
      }
    }

    pollClient.stop();
    Serial.println("Closing poll client connection.");
  }

  delay(50);
}

String split(String data, char delimiter, int index) {
  int found = 0;
  int strIndex[] = {0, -1};
  int maxIndex = data.length()-1;

  for(int i=0; i<=maxIndex && found<=index; i++){
    if(data.charAt(i)==delimiter || i==maxIndex){
        found++;
        strIndex[0] = strIndex[1]+1;
        strIndex[1] = (i == maxIndex) ? i+1 : i;
    }
  }

  return found>index ? data.substring(strIndex[0], strIndex[1]) : "";
}

void isort(int *a, int n) {
  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    int j = a[i];
    int k;
    for (k = i - 1; (k >= 0) && (j < a[k]); k--) {
      a[k + 1] = a[k];
    }
    a[k + 1] = j;
  }
}

int mode(int *x,int n){

  int i = 0;
  int count = 0;
  int maxCount = 0;
  int mode = 0;
  int bimodal;
  int prevCount = 0;
  while(i<(n-1)){
    prevCount=count;
    count=0;
    while(x[i]==x[i+1]){
      count++;
      i++;
    }
    if(count>prevCount&count>maxCount){
      mode=x[i];
      maxCount=count;
      bimodal=0;
    }
    if(count==0){
      i++;
    }
    if(count==maxCount){//If the dataset has 2 or more modes.
      bimodal=1;
    }
    if(mode==0||bimodal==1){//Return the median if there is no mode.
      mode=x[(n/2)];
    }
    return mode;
  }
}

void printArray(int *a, int n) {

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(a[i], DEC);
    Serial.print(' ');
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void pingSonars() {
  digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_SONARS; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < numPulses; j++) {
      pulse = pulseIn(sonarPin[i], HIGH);
      pulseArray[j] = pulse/147; //convert to inches -- 147 uS per inches
      delay(5);
    }
    isort(pulseArray, numPulses);
    filteredMode = mode(pulseArray,numPulses);
    //printArray(pulseArray,numPulses);
    Serial.print("Filtered distance for Sonar ");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(": ");
    Serial.println(filteredMode);
    if((filteredMode < sonarThreshold) && !sonarState[i]) {
      //if we are closer than the threshold and previously were not, this is a rising edge:
      Serial.print("Sonar ");
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.println(" triggered!");
      sonarState[i] = 1;
    }
    else if (filteredMode > sonarThreshold && sonarState[i]) {
    //if we are greater than the threshold and previously were, this is a falling edge:
      Serial.print("Sonar ");
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.println(" falling!");
      sonarState[i] = 0;
    }
      //always respond to a poll with the current state
      content_string = "PUT\nSONAR ";
      content_string += String(i);
      content_string += "= ";
      content_string += String(sonarState[i]);
      content_string += "\n\n";
      localClient->post_request(content_string);
  }
}
```

which sends the PUT message to server.py

```
import socket

host = '192.168.0.100'
port = 8220
address = (host, port)

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((address))
server_socket.listen(5)

while True:
    try:
        print "Listening for client . . ."
        conn, address = server_socket.accept()
        print "Connected to client at ", address
        #pick a large output buffer size because i dont necessarily know how big the incoming packet is
        output = conn.recv(2048);
        if output:
            print "Message received from client:"
            print output

        #conn.send("This is a response from the server.")
        conn.close()
        #print "Test message sent and connection closed."
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print
        print "Stop."
        break
```

For reference, MyClient is a wrapper around ethernet that I used for sending HTTP-style (but not HTTP-compliant) messages:

```
#include <WProgram.h>
#include "MyClient.h"

MyClient::MyClient(byte* mac_address, byte* ip_address) {
  Serial.println("Initializing HTTP Client...");
  Ethernet.begin(mac_address, ip_address);
  Serial.print("My IP address: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  delay(1000);
  debug = true;
}

void MyClient::connect(byte* server_address, int port) {
  //server = server_address;
  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to server at ");
  Serial.print(server_address[0]);
  Serial.print(".");
  Serial.print(server_address[1]);
  Serial.print(".");
  Serial.print(server_address[2]);
  Serial.print(".");
  Serial.print(server_address[3]);
  Serial.print("...");
  while(!client.connect(server_address, port)) {
    ;
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to server!");
}

void MyClient::disconnect() {
  client.stop();
}

bool MyClient::connected() {
  return client.connected();
}

void MyClient::get_request(String resource) {
  if(debug) {
    Serial.println("Submitting GET request.");
  }
 // Make a HTTP request:
    client.print("GET ");
    client.print(resource);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    print_host(server);    
    client.println("User-Agent: sdfSensorClient/0.1");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
}

void MyClient::post_request(String content) {
  if(debug) {
    Serial.println("Making a POST request.");
  }
  content += "[/TCP]";
  client.println(content);
  if(debug) {
    Serial.println("Posted:");
    Serial.println(content);
  }
}

void MyClient::print_host(byte* host) {
  client.print("Host: ");
  client.print(host[0]);
  client.print(".");
  client.print(host[1]);
  client.print(".");
  client.print(host[2]);
  client.print(".");
  client.println(host[3]);
}

void MyClient::get_response() {
  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    if(debug) {
      Serial.print(c);
    }
  }
}

bool MyClient::get_status() {
  return client.connected();
}

void MyClient::set_debug(bool status) {
  debug = status;
}
```